# How strictly should the close-as-duplicate rule be enforced?

Tags: discussion, flagging

[**Here are the reasons why questions are sometimes closed as duplicates**](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). Read this first.

The Stack Exchange rules about duplicate questions were recently relaxed --in a recent post that I can't find-- that linked to this 2010 document.

I just posted this as a [comment](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16710/contesting-dialog/16711#comment27083_16710):

> I see that there are two *close as duplicate* votes on [this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16710/contesting-dialog). I am not going to interfere if it does get closed, but this seems like a good place to remind everyone that **the [rules on duplicates were relaxed somewhat](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)**. The community's (that's you!) opinions matter more than the moderators. :-)

---

Here's the lowdown on *To flag, or not to flag, that is the question*:

### [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

> As Stack Overflow grows — or any other Q&A; site in the Stack Exchange network, really — there’s a natural pressure to discover and link duplicate questions. The more questions you have, the higher the possibility a given new question isn’t in fact a new question, but a duplicate of an older existing question. [Because…](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as strictly as in years past.

It would be a good idea to review the [linked page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) in the question before you [flag a question as a duplicate](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).

This is *not* to discourage anyone from flagging questions. There has always been --and will always be-- bona fide [reasons for flagging posts as duplicate](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).